# Watch Connectivity not starting

Tags: watchconnectivity

My Watch Connectivity is not working at all - no response, but also no error messages.
I have copied in a WatchSessionManager and all Swift files including Extension Delegate from another Swift 2.2 project where it works fine. But on my new project it gives no response. I've tried starting the partner iPhone, and it doesn't trigger it.
Are there any project settings that I have to change or frameworks I need to add for watch connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. In Capabilities I turned on 'background modes' and selected 'audio, airplay and picture in picture' and 'background fetch'.